# The gauge of a wire vs electrical resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

For my experiment, I set up a series circuit. I had to use 3 different gauges of copper wires and test them against electrical resistances. My results were:

$$
\begin{array}{rccc}
\text{12-gauge wire:} & 0.04 \, \mathrm{A} & 0.004 \, \mathrm{V} & 0.025\, \Omega \\
 \text{8-gauge wire:} & 0.04 \, \mathrm{A} & 0.003 \, \mathrm{V} & 0.075\, \Omega \\
 \text{4-gauge wire:} & 0.04 \, \mathrm{A} & 0.001 \, \mathrm{V} & 0.1\phantom{00}\, \Omega \\
\end{array}
$$

I have to fill out this table:
[image]

But I'm not sure how to fill out the average and standard deviation part, nor if i filled out the independent and dependent variable part out right.

Comment: Related question by OP:  [How would you calculate the averages and standard deviations for this experiment?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/411294/9887)

Comment: Related question by OP:  [Dependent and Independent Variables in an Electrical Experiment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/411286/9887)

Comment: VTC and down-vote for taking the good will of the volunteers here for granted.

Comment: This is the US Common Core format. It is often very poorly adapted to an experiment or even contrived measurements that don't fit the format. I can't say I blame the students.

Comment: Please do not re-post questions.

Answer (score 0):

if you are required to furnish an **average** and a **standard deviation** it means you have to take not just one but a bunch of measurements at each experimental condition and then solve for their average and for the amount of spread or scatter in those measurements using the standard statistics formulae that exist for this purpose.